# Refresh Items of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn after DataSource Change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` called `myCmb`:

```
        DataTable dtLevel = Level.SearchLevel(id);

        myCmb.DataSource = dtLevel;
        myCmb.ValueMember = "idLevel";
        myCmb.DisplayMember = "cLevel";
```

This is inside a method, at the first time it's ok but when the method is called for second time it seems there's a problem with `Items` property of myCmb because `myCmb.Items.Count` is 0 and there's an error When I show this cell in the grid.

How can I refresh `Items` of `myCmb` when datasource change?

Comment: What is the error? Also you can try to bind the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a `BindingSource`, then update the `DataSource` of it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the datasource to `null` before setting the values. The code below should work fine.

```
DataTable dtLevel = Level.SearchLevel(id);
myCmb.DataSource = null;
myCmb.DataSource = dtLevel;
myCmb.ValueMember = "idLevel";
myCmb.DisplayMember = "cLevel";
```

Hope this helps!